# It's from a wide, thick spectrum of cream

Tags: word-usage, listening

At video on minutes 9:20
https://youtu.be/MnlPfvx7Cgg?t=559

The speaker mentioned "top 'cream' of Singapore"

I found the definition of "the cream of sth" *the best of a particular group of things or people:* ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cream)) but in the video at 9:28 that say

> "it's from a wide, thick spectrum of cream -

which do not seem to be in the form of "the cream of sth"

Is there a more comprehensive dictionary that I can look up to explain the usage of cream in "it's from a wide, thick spectrum of cream"?

Comment: Have you used a dictionary?  Can you tell us what possibilities you have found.  The first one is "The thick milky substance"..  Why do you suppose this isn't correct?

Comment: @JamesK not suggest that it's incorrect, but I can't hear the word sound by "cream" - I do find a dictionary to find similar sound words but failed

Comment: @JamesK Do you suggest that the right word is cream? I do a check here - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cream, the most related is an idiom "the cream of sth", and later part of video it mentions (9:28) "it's from a wide, think spectrum of cream - which do not seem to be in the form of "the cream of sth"

Comment: "Spectrum of cream" is a stupidly forced and mixed metaphor and a very clumsy use of language. Was this a native English speaker? It is no wonder that william007 cannot make out its meaning. This illustrates how many Youtube videos are very poor learning resources.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the video, it sounds like a play on the expression **["the cream of [something]"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cream-of-sth)**, which means "the best of [something]":

> **the cream of sth**
> the best of a particular group of things or people

In this video specifically, the word "cream" is being used as a metaphor, particularly in the second half of his sentence where he refers to a "pretty wide spectrum of cream". The interpretation therefore depends entirely on the context. In this case, it seems to be a metaphor for a person:

> They are just the top cream of Singapore, whereas on the other side, they are part of a pretty wide, thick spectrum of cream.

> They are just the top people of Singapore, whereas on the other side, they are part of a wide spectrum of people.

These have the same meaning in this context.

The usage of the word "cream" by the speaker isn't wrong, he's just doing a play on words and speaking in a poetic way.